# error helm install on AKS -- context deadline exceeded

Tags: azure, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

I am trying to Install Nginx ingress controller on AKS ,but it is failing with below error

```
Error: query: failed to query with labels: Internal error occurred: unable to transform key "/registry/secrets/nginx-ingress/nginx-ingress-nginx-ingress-default-server-tls": rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded
```

I already installed nginx last week with same configuration ,but while upgrading i see this error

even while uninstalling same nginx through helm i can see this error

I tried to change some variables in values.yaml but it didn't help

Comment: you can try changing timeout, default is 5m.
https://helm.sh/docs/intro/using_helm/#helpful-options-for-installupgraderollback

Answer (score 0):

you can try using below steps to install nginx controller on your AKS using helm.
Assuming your AKS cluster is already up as below

[image: https://i.imgur.com/E7CddcT.png]

Create a seperate namespace called `ingress`

```
kubectl create namespace ingress
```

[image: https://i.imgur.com/1wXiQbZ.png]

Using helm, install nginx-ingress-

```
 helm install nginx-ingress nginx/ingress-nginx --wait --namespace ingress --set defaultBackend.nodeSelector."kubernetes.io/os"=linux

helm repo update
```

[image: https://i.imgur.com/leNfZ0X.png]

Switch to ingress namespace using-

```
kubectl config set-context --current --namespace=ingress
```

[image: https://i.imgur.com/vWBSJM1.png]

Your nginx ingress controller pod is now ready.

```
kubectl get pods -n ingress
```

[image: https://i.imgur.com/5vGSsBI.png]

[Official MS doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-basic?tabs=azure-cli)